# Ionic 4: The "src" content of an "img" tag is not updating when I change it from the controller in IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing an app for Android and IOS.

I have a profile page where the user can change profile pictures. The photo appears in the view and is changed in real time.

My code is like this in the view:

```
<img alt="logo" style="width:15vh; height:15vh; border-radius: 50%;" src="{{pictureusuariomenu}}">
```

**pictureusuariomenu** is a variable found in the controller.

With that variable what I do is, it is the URL of the image that I upload, I update it there.  here is the function:

```
updateStoredImages(name) {
    this.storage.get(STORAGE_KEY).then(images => {
        let arr = JSON.parse(images);
        if (!arr) {
            let newImages = [name];
            this.storage.set(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(newImages));
        } else {
            arr.push(name);
            this.storage.set(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(arr));
        }

        let filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + name;
        let resPath = this.pathForImage(filePath);
       // alert(resPath);
        this.urlImage=resPath;


        let newEntry = {
            name: name,
            path: resPath,
            filePath: filePath
        };
        this.images=[]; //borrar las imagenes anteriores (no crear la lista de imagenes)
        this.images = [newEntry, ...this.images];
        this.urlImage = this.images[0].path;
        this.colocarImagenEnProfile(this.urlImage);     
        this.ref.detectChanges(); // trigger change detection cycle
    });
}
```

In this line:

```
this.colocarImagenEnProfile(this.urlImage);
```

What I do is:

```
colocarImagenEnProfile(newFileName){
    this.pictureusuariomenu=newFileName;
}
```

Now in android is working fine this way of updating the profile image in view:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

But in IOS this isn't working.   The view is not updated at all

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Nothing appears, just a few letters. But the view doesn't update in IOS.

**What could it be?**

My specifications:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to bind it. put it instead of your HTML tag:

```
<img alt="logo" style="width:15vh; height:15vh; border-radius: 50%;" [src]="pictureusuariomenu">
```

I don't know why but you have to bind it that way.
also, you have to use window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(); function, if using angular you need to sanitize it. like this:

```
this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(path))
```